# Angularjs : REST Api How to refresh json data with only the changed content (ivh-tree)

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, tree

I have a REST API call which fetches JSON data in tree format....

Now, i store that in a scope variable $scope.treeData []

And this is connected to a ivh-tree.

Now, i am using interval to update this data every 60 secs

The problem is:
The moment the new data is fetched and replaced in the scope variable, all the properties of the tree is lost and its re-initialized to default (the new data is present though).
By Properties, i mean, checkbox selections or node expansions etc.
The tree refreshes to the basic minimal unexpanded format.

So, is there a way by which i can update the existing  scope variable with only the changed data i.e. add new nodes or remove existing nodes or change some property ?

Or is there any tree widget which i can use.
Its difficult in finding angular components for tree which atleast preserve the tree state on data update

Comment: seems like the key work is `replaced`. API for directive has methods to add nodes. Would do that instead of `replace`

Comment: Hi charlie.... could you give me some more details

Comment: I've never used this tree but it is explained how to add nodes in the docs

Answer (score 0):

To add the new nodes you could use angular.merge:

```
angular.merge($scope.treeData, json.treeData)
```

You would still have to remove the elements manually though.

https://jsfiddle.net/g24rbcur/2/

Comment: I should add that this is only supported in angular 1.4